# NextAuth: Recommended way for extending the sessions user object for multiple user types?

Tags: next-auth

I'm creating a web app that's similar to Fiverr/UpWork where users have the option to become sellers to offer their services. I'm using NextAuth with the Prisma Adapter (with MongoDB) which is storing the generic `user` object in my `Users` collection in my database with the following structure:

```
{
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  image: string;
}
```

If a user chooses to become a seller, they will need to create a seller profile to give additional details, such as their bio, education, skills, etc., and I am planning on storing these additional details in a separate `Sellers` collection, and relating them via a Foreign Key as follows:

```
{
  id: string;
  userId: string; // Foreign Key
  bio: string;
  skills: string[];
  otherAdditionalItems: any;
}
```

**My question is this:** using NextAuth, what is the recommended way to fetch a user's **seller profile** when they sign in and have access to this on the client? And where should this be stored? Can I somehow store the seller profile on the NextAuth sessions `user` object (after the separate seller profile is fetched) so that it's accessible via `session.user`? Or will I need to store the seller profile in some sort of state management solution such as Redux?

I can't seem to find a recommended way to do something like this so would love any sort of input/help!

Much appreciated.